# Major issues trying to copy files from one WD SSD to another: sizes inflate drastically, weird error messages?

Tags: terminal, finder, backup, ssd, external-disk

I have two [Western Digital Elements external 1 TB SSD](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B097TTZD48) drives.  One of them has about 900GB of files that come from an older Mac that I want to back up onto the second.  I have about 850GB of free space on the second, so I know not all of them will fit.   (In the discussion below, the **origin** volume is 'elements' with a lower-case 'e'; the **destination/target** volume is 'Elements' with a capital 'E')

I started by trying to copy the "Pictures" folder (which comes from iPhoto).  This folder is about 185GB, according to the Finder (command+i --> folder information).

I have tried to copy it to the second SSD twice now, first by dragging in the finder (or, specifically, copying and pasting).  This ended (after some hours) with the message that not all files could fit.

I then tried it through Terminal (again, just the 185GB *Pictures* folder, not the entire contents), using

```
cp -Rnv
```

(-R for recursive, -n to make sure nothing was overwritten, although that should have been impossible, and -v so I got a transcript). It chugged along overnight, but when I came back this morning, in the transcript there appear many lines that indicate successful copies (I've edited the line to remove some personal info):

```
/Volumes/elements 1/abc/Pictures/Misc/2010-06-22 2010/2010 1277.JPG -> /Volumes/Elements/Pictures/Misc/2010-06-22 2010/ 2010 1277.JPG
```

But I also got a huge amount of lines saying that specific files/folders did not exist:

```
cp: /Volumes/Elements/Pictures/Photos Library.photoslibrary/Thumbnails/2014/11/02/20141102-141219/qxD5nhKVSeqcRsqA88+l+Q/IMG_6849_1024.jpg: No such file or directory
```

(since "Elements" with a capital E is the target volume, perhaps this simply indicates that the file didn't copy?)

as well as at the end of everything about 10 lines in this format:

```
cp: /Volumes/elements 1/abc/Pictures/WLM14ES_-abdefg-SOMETHING_SOMETHING.jpg: No space left on device
```

showing no space left.

And indeed there is no space left on the volume.

I'm really confused.  I don't understand how 185GB of files can swell to more than 850GB of files on the target volume, particularly since the drives are functionally identical.  They may have been formatted differently: I know the origin volume was formatted to allow it to have a password.  And yet, still, why such a huge leap?  And what am I going to do to backup the first volume, since I have 900GB of data?  Will I need many terabytes to do so?

Finally, what are the cryptic messages ("file not found") indicating?

I'm not inexperienced with Macs, being a programmer, and having used them for many years.  But this is frustrating and beyond me.

Is there a better method to accomplish what I want?  A different unix command?  The destination volume has about 50GB of other files on it.  Do I need to remove those and reformat the destination volume?

And what do all the hundreds/thousands of error lines with "file not found" indicate?

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: By any chance, you have any sort of symlink (hard or soft) in the source folder?  The error "file not found" is self explanatory - it can't find the file.  Try the `cp` command with a `-v` (verbose) flag so you get more details.  As for a better method, it would help if we had a better picture of what we were working with on the source.  At first glance, you could use `rsync` or if these are to be archived, maybe `tar` is a better fit.

Comment: @Allan -- thanks.  The curious thing is that the error messages are referring (as best I can see) to not finding the files on the _destination_ drive, not the source drive.   I did use the -v flag, as I noted, which is how I was able to get the error messages.  I'm not sure how to specify more precisely the nature of the source: it is the iPhoto folder from an iMac, so it has photos, and that other data structures/files on which iPhoto depends (thumbs, data, etc).  Lastly, how would I use 'rsync' to better move things?  I'm afraid I'm not familiar with that command.

Comment: Try appending `>> errors.txt 2>&1 ` to redirect the error messages to a file.  Then you can parse it at your leisure.

Comment: I have all the errors saved, but I'm not sure why they're being produced.  The source drive was re-formatted.  Could different formatting of the two drives produce an issue with smaller size files on the source drive somehow being inflated (in size) on the destination drive?

Comment: Please post a sampling of errors or share the file via iCloud, OneDrive, [PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/) or similar service.  Please [edit] the question with the sample edits and/or link to the shared error file.

Comment: My reticence to post the original file was that it had a lot of personal info on it (deducible through file and folder names).  That could be edited out, of course, but we are talking about thousands or tens of thousands of lines.  In any case the drive died a couple of days ago -- it suddenly would not mount.  So I'm at a bit of a loss there.  I ordered a 2TB WD HDD and that worked fine.  Perhaps there was something wrong with the SSD to begin with...